# Apache CXF java2ws plugin

Tags: java, apache, maven, cxf

There is a soap web service is generated using CXF java2ws plugin and I want to add a new web service. How to do it? My current maven configurations for java2ws:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-java2ws-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>process-classes</phase>
            <configuration>
                <className>com.test.push.api.WebServicesInt</className>
                <serviceName>WebServicesSer</serviceName>
                <genWsdl>true</genWsdl>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>java2ws</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

The maven configuration you are showing is about creating wsdl, not about creating web service itself (which is creating new java-class with proper annotations, google will provide good tutorials about that one )